# Magento : How To Create Edit Product Page On Frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

I've created this page on frontend.

[image]

I want input field fills with values product based on product id.

I have blank controller. How can I update product attribute in this form trough my controller and my `.phtml` file.

Comment: provide your block controller and template file

Comment: still blank for all @GopalPatel

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In your controller you can load that product using

**$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);**

and then pass that product object to your phtml file using register i.e

**Mage::register('product', $product->getData());**

then in phtml get that product object using

**$product_data = Mage::registry('product');**

then you will get the product data in form of array.